# How to install UI framework Quasar to existing Vue JS project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a project in Vue JS I need some components (for example range) which I want to apply for my project, my problem is that I do not quite understand how these components can be applied in my project, since I looked at some tutorials installing [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/installation) from scratch but the problem is that they first set the global variable using **"npm install -g @ quasar / cli"** and then create a new project using the command **"quasar create <folder_name>"**

but as you already understood I need to create a project zone I already have a project, I only need to install [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/installation) and then use those components from the box that I need, I remember when I was still working in React, I did not have such problems

Comment: You can't. `Unfortunately, to get the full Quasar set of capabilities, the project needs to be a Quasar CLI project. Best thing to do is port your project over to a Quasar project. Shouldn’t be too difficult either, as Quasar is built around Vue, so all of your work should generally work with Quasar too. If you are using Vue plug-ins, you might need to build boot files to integrate them. Other than that, I don’t see any difficulties.` Please see this on the quasar form https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/6731/add-quasar-to-existing-vue-project/3

Comment: It's strange you can not just execute npm install and be done with it :\.. I think you can just run `vue add quasar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use quasar with Vue CLI plugin:

with Vue 3:
https://quasar.dev/start/vue-cli-plugin

with Vue 2:
https://v1.quasar.dev/start/vue-cli-plugin

Comment: Indeed, so you need to run: `vue add quasar`